# xpages inputfield send data from datepicker to server

Tags: xpages, bootstrap-datepicker

On my xpages I have an inputfield:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputPassExpiryDate"
value="#{customerBean.customer.dateValidPass}"
disabled="#{!customerBean.customer.editMode}"
validator="#{customerValidators.validPassDate}">
</xp:inputText>
```

I enable a datapicker plugin (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) for the inputfield with the following script:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function(){
    reloadDP();
    var dateFormat = "#{javascript: application['date_only']}";
        x$('#{id:inputPassExpiryDate}').datepicker({
            language: getUserLanguage(),              
            format:(dateFormat),
            weekStart: 1,
            todayBtn: true,
            clearBtn: true,
            daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
            calendarWeeks: true,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('changeDate', doSomething);
    }        
)

function doSomething(){
    var from = x$('#{id:inputPassExpiryDate}').val().split("-")
    var DateInput = new Date(from[0], from[1] - 1, from[2])
    var DateNow = new Date();
    if (DateInput <= DateNow) {
        x$('#{id:inputPassExpiryDate}').addClass("invalid");
        x$('#{id:pnlExpiredReason}').removeClass("hidden"); 
    }else{
        x$('#{id:inputPassExpiryDate}').removeClass("invalid");
        x$('#{id:pnlExpiredReason}').addClass("hidden");    
    }
}
```

I notice that a change in date is only set in the web client.

In element 'pnlExpiredReason' I have an textarea control which I would like to validate when submitting to the server ONLY when inputPassExpiryDate has a date that is older than the current date.

But I notice that the changed value for inputPassExpiryDate is not changed when I submit the xpage to the server and validation starts. It simply has the same value as it has before I changed value with the date picker.

So my question is how can I update the value for the inputfield (server-side) when I have changed the value via the date-picker (client-side) ?

```
getComponent("inputPassExpiryDate").getValue()
```

will return the value that the date-pciker had when the xpage was loaded, not after update via the date-picker.

Comment: Are you submitting the whole page to the server or at least partially refreshing an area that contains the inputPassExpiryDate control?

Comment: I am submitting the whole page. I found some help here: https://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/752C5BDF6ACA502D86258116005978F9 to perform a XSP.partialRefreshPost. Oddly when I partially refresh the visibility property for a panel, the visibility property is re-caclulated but the panel is not recalculated/rendered

Comment: Just to be clear: when you submit the whole page, the changed data in the inputPassExpiryDate field is not visible on the server? Have you checked in network properties whether the content is sent as part of the post?